# Excel 2010 - Hyperlink Text Only & Not Entire Cell

Tags: excel, hyperlink

Is there a way to add a hyperlink to text only and not the entire cell in Excel 2010?

I am only able to insert a hyperlink which affects the entire cell (even white space after the text), but I wish to have it so that a user can click on the non-hyperlinked section of the cell in order to select the cell without activating the hyperlink.

Is this possible (ideally without VB)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure.. I just wrote this, but it acts the same as adding a hyper reference (although you can still select the whitespace of a cell (after the text has finished) and it won't follow the link)

```
=CONCATENATE("This is your ", HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com","Google"), " link")
```

Just as a FYI, you can hold ALT key and click on a cell without it opening the URI

Comment: Thank you for this - I have tried it and it works well; I am just going to customise it to suit my specific purpose.  I tried the `ALT` + click option but it brings up the 'Reference' panel to the right of the screen each time.  Thanks again!

Comment: I tried this but Excel 2010 still shows the entire cell clickable.

Comment: Same here .. concatenate does not seem to be able to prepend or append anything to a hyperlink that does not then become a link (and usually an erroneous one, so it's useless).  Sucks because I really wanted to build the table in Excel and then paste into Word - can only pull off the hyperlink and plain text in a table cell in Word.

Answer (score 5):

I got over this by turning off the "wrap text" from the cell formatting.

Answer (score 3):

really, if you have wrap text turned on, the whole cell will act as a hyperlink. if you have wrap text turned off, only text will act as a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

An indent (Home → Alignment → Indent: 1) makes the entire cell a hyperlink.

Answer (score -1):

It's a very odd thing. If I link to a .doc or docx document, only the text is linked. If I link to a .txt document, the whole cell is a link. 
I think it's just an odd excel glitch.