# Excel - link to another cell from the middle of the text

Tags: excel

I am conceived, that we can hyperlink some cell within the another cell text.

I was trying to do something like this:

[image]

[image]

But it doesn't work.

```
         "The locality sketch indicates" &'Frontsheet!D13'&" location: Building Overview"
```

These links:
[How to replace the middle of an Excel cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535003/how-to-replace-the-middle-of-an-excel-cell)
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/work-with-hyperlinks-in-excel-7fc80d8d-68f9-482f-ab01-584c44d72b3e
[Excel 2010 - Hyperlink Text Only & Not Entire Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842407/excel-2010-hyperlink-text-only-not-entire-cell)

doesn't really help.

I would like to have an active link to another cell, embedded inside the text in the active cell. Is it possible?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/428299/hyperlinking-a-piece-of-text-in-excel. I'm not sure why there's an accepted answer to that last link you mentioned. Definitely does not work (at least in Excel 2016). I'm not sure this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The concatenation is not needed, because we can do it like this:

```
  ="Photograph indicates the entrance elevation of "&Frontsheet!D27&"."
```

placing the `=` before quote, next put everything inside the quote and use & for separation between our text and link in the cell. The Quote indicates our text. `&` - indicates what we want to hyperlink. If I wouldn't back to the quote here `"."` my sentence works without the dot at the end.

[image]